# Creating a Sudoku Grid (Javascript and HTML), won't allow input to cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, sudoku, zepto

So I've got my program running, where it creates a sudoku grid, and has a single-row table beneath it, to allow number input.

[image]

But, when I click on a number at the bottom and click a cell so that the number can go into the cell, it won't work. (I double clicked, to show that I had clicked it)

[image]

I selected 1, and clicked on a cell, wanting a 1 to appear in that cell. But instead, it does nothing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Generated Sudoku">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js"></script>
    <title>Sudoku Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sudoku</h1>
    <table id="sudokuTable">
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="numberSelector">1</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">2</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">3</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">4</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">5</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">6</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">7</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">8</td>
          <td class="numberSelector">9</td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" onclick="createSudokuTable()">New</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
td {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.numberSelector {
  background-color:blue;
  color:yellow;
  font-family:Arial,Sans-Serif;
}
.selectedNumber {
  background-color:yellow;
  color:blue;
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function createSudokuTable() {
    var htmlText = '';
    for (var row = 1; row <= 9; row++) {
        htmlText += '<tr>';
        for (var column = 1; column <= 9; column++) {
            htmlText += '<td class="sudokuCell" id="cell_' + row + '_' + column + '">&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        htmlText += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#sudokuTable').html(htmlText);
}
var inputNumber = 1;
function clicked() {
    cellId = this.id;
    if ($('#' + cellId).text() == inputNumber) {
        $('#' + cellId).text('&nbsp;');
    } else {
        $('#' + cellId).text(inputNumber);
    }
}



function selectNumber() {
    inputNumber = this.innerText;
    $('.numberSelector').removeClass('selectedNumber');
    $(this).addClass('selectedNumber');
}

$('.sudokuCell').on('click', clicked);
$('.numberSelector').on('click', selectNumber);
```

I have used Zepto by the way :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
$('.sudokuCell').on('click', clicked);
```

You are attaching the handler on `click` event of the `.sudokuCell` element which does not exist at the time of page load. You have to **delegate the event** handling to the nearest parent which exists at the time of event attachment.

To solve this, make this simple change in your code:

```
$('#sudokuTable').on('click','.sudokuCell', clicked);
```

Check the complete functional code here: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vapukacipa/edit?html,js,output)

Learn more about event delegation here: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)